# How can I pass value of this JSON in objective-c?

Tags: objective-c, json

```
weather =     (
            {
        description = mist;
        icon = 50n;
        id = 701;
        main = Mist;
    },
            {
        description = "heavy intensity drizzle";
        icon = 09n;
        id = 302;
        main = Drizzle;
    }
)
```

I want to fetch "main" from this, 
i am doing this using this

```
NSDictionary *dic1 = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data options:0 error:&error];
NSDictionary *dic4 = [dic1 objectForKey:@"weather"];

NSString * weatherStr =  
    [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Weather type:%@",[dic4 valueForKey:@"main"]];
weathertypeLabel.text =  
    [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Weather type:%@",weatherStr];
```

but my o/p is

```
Weather type:(
    Mist,
    Drizzle
)
```

Comment: I'm not sure you are aware of it but there is an _array_ in your JSON, which you totally ignore seemingly; so accessing the __first__ `main` is supposed to look something like this: `NSString *_mistText = [[[dic1 objectForKey:@"weather"] objectAtIndex:0] valueForKey:@"main"]; // "Mist"`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
NSString * weatherStr =  
[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Weather type:%@",[dic4 valueForKey:@"main"]];
```

**Use This**

```
 NSString * weatherStr =  
[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Weather type:%@",[[dic4 objectForKey:@"weather"]objectForKey :@"main"]];
```

Answer (score 2):

You are just kidding yourself when you say this:

```
NSDictionary *dic4 = [dic1 objectForKey:@"weather"];
```

In spite of your declaration, `dic4` is *not* a dictionary. It is an array (NSArray) of dictionaries, containing two dictionaries. And so you are fetching the `"main"` key's value from *both of them at once*.

If that's not what you want, then you need to decide which dictionary you want, `dic4[0]` or `dict4[1]`. Extract it, and fetch its `"main"`.

Comment: @iOS.developer `dic4` is clearly an `NSArray`, matt is absolutely right. The output is an array representation because you are mousetrapped in KVC.

Comment: ok  my mistake.Thank you both.i am very new to this so learning.

Comment: You won't learn, though, if you argue instead. You are the asker of the question; this means you don't know the answer. If you knew what you were doing you wouldn't be having the problem in the first place.

Comment: ya thats true. my bad sorry.